# Сложение чисел до и после запятой

Tags: c#

Написал код, но он не работает. Что я неправильно делаю?

```C#
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp12
{
    class Program

    {
        class FloatNum
        {
            ulong integerPart;
            ulong fractionalPart;
            ulong d;
            public FloatNum(ulong integerPart, ulong fractionalPart)
            {
                this.integerPart = integerPart;
                this.fractionalPart = fractionalPart;
                d = 1;
                while (fractionalPart > 0)
                {
                    d *= 10;
                    fractionalPart /= 10;
                }
            }
            public void plus(FloatNum secondFloat)
            {
                this.integerPart += secondFloat.integerPart;
                ulong frResult = this.fractionalPart + secondFloat.fractionalPart;
                this.integerPart += frResult / this.d;
                this.fractionalPart = frResult % this.d;
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                FloatNum fl = new FloatNum(5, 123);
                FloatNum fl1 = new FloatNum(6, 921);
                fl.plus(fl1);
                Console.WriteLine(fl);
                Console.WriteLine(fl1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему, самая большая проблема в этой строке:

```
ulong frResult = this.fractionalPart + secondFloat.fractionalPart;
```

Эта строка неявно предполагает, что количество знаков после запятой в обоих слагаемых одинаково. Это вовсе не обязательно так. Если ваши исходные числа `new FloatNum(0, 1)` и `new FloatNum(0, 11)`, то при сложении дробных частей вы получите 12, а не 21.

Следующая проблема — ваш формат вовсе не позволяет выразить числа наподобие `1,01`: ведущие нули в числах игнорируются, и в вашем конструкторе нет никакой возможности отличить случай `1,01` от `1,1`.

Ещё одна мелкая проблема: у вас *разрушающее* сложение: сумма чисел записывается в первое слагаемое, таким образом, после сложения исходное число исчезает. Обычно всё же реализуют неразрушающее сложение, при котором слагаемые не меняются, а создаётся новое число, содержащее результат (благо C# содержит сборщик мусора, и о тонкостях владения результатами сложения можно не думать).

---

Что нужно делать? Необходимо отказаться от вашего метода хранения, и хранить целую и дробную часть вместе, в *одном* числе. Таким образом, у вам будет одно число, отвечающее за все десятичные знаки (*мантисса*), а также число, показывающее, сколько из этих знаков находится после запятой (*порядок*).

При сложении вам придётся обеспечить *одинаковые* порядки, для этого мантиссу числа с меньшим порядком придётся несколько раз умножить на 10 перед сложением.